# Is there a function to shift degrees of a circle past 0?

Tags: delphi, math, geometry, delphi-xe2

I'm looking for a function somewhere in Delphi XE2 similar to `Inc()` which allows me to add/subtract a number of degrees from a current number of degrees and result in the new degrees. For example, if I have a point currently at 5 degrees around a circle, and I want to subtract 10, I should not get -5 degrees, but rather 355 (360 - 5). Same as adding past 360 - it should go back to 0 when it reaches 360.

Is there anything like this already in Delphi so I don't have to re-write it? Perhaps in the `Math` unit?

Comment: For the record: Delphi XE3 does have a DegNormalize() function in System.Math.

Comment: I'd like to comment that this question, answers and comments epitomise why I love Stack Overflow. I've learnt a lot about one tiny little function that I thought I already had licked. Well played everyone!

Comment: All this knowledge locked away in developers' heads and code and we don't know what we don't know... That's the beauty of expanding our expertise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,Math;

Function WrapAngle( angle : Double) : Double;
Const
  modAngle : Double = 360.0;
begin
  Result := angle - modAngle*Floor(angle/modAngle);
end;

begin
  WriteLn(FloatToStr(WrapAngle(-5)));
  WriteLn(FloatToStr(WrapAngle(5-720)));
  WriteLn(FloatToStr(WrapAngle(360)));
  ReadLn;    
end.
```

Produces result:

```
355
5 
0
```

Update:

As @Giel found, in XE3 there is a new function `DegNormalize()` which does the job. Even about 25% faster. The trick is to replace the `Floor()` call with an `Int()` instead, and if the result is negative, add `modAngle` to the result.

Comment: Thanks, I use it a lot in my applications. By substituting the modAngle to 2*Pi you have a working function for radians as well.

Comment: Indeed. Or pass modulus as parameter. My version seems needlessly complex. I think we use some of the helpers in other routines.

Comment: +1, and deleted mine. Nice, and handles invalid values as well.

Comment: @Ken Have a look at revision 1 of your now deleted answer. I guess something went astray when you posted. I think the code you originally posted wasn't quite the same as the code in your IDE when you generated output. My point being that Marjan didn't break your code. She was trying to fix it. But she didn't even manage that. Anyway, LURD's answer is clearly the one. Floating point. Accepts input in any range. Sweet.

Comment: @David: Thanks. Not sure what happened with the code (mea culpa, obviously). I never suggested that anyone (especially Marjan) broke anything; I just intended to point out that I actually tested the code. Seems I got things out of synch somewhere. (The point is a little moot, though, since I deleted the answer very shortly after making the edit this morning.) :-)

Comment: Not sure whether to call them "invalid values" because a value of 720 can be very legitimate. For example, if I'm continuously spinning a ball around the edge of a circle, in a "winding" motion, and it's expected to spin back the other direction the same amount to get back to 0, then I might wind up adding over 2,000 into this function, which should still fall within the 0..360 range. This function by LU RD seems perfect.

Comment: @Jerry It's true, winding can lead to many multiples of 360. Also, am I right in guessing that you use floating point?

Comment: Yes, and that's something I didn't think about when asking.

Answer (score 4):

```
function WrapAngle(Value: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := Value mod 360;
  if Result < 0 then
    Inc(Result, 360);
end;
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest you can do for integer input.

Answer (score 3):

The code I use to perform this task is:

```
function PosFrac(x: Double): Double;
(* PosFrac(1.2)=0.2 and PosFrac(-1.2)=0.8. *)
begin
  Result := Frac(x); (* Frac(x)=x-Int(x) *)
  if Result<0.0 then begin
    Result := 1.0+Result;
  end;
end;

function ModR(const x, y: Double): Double;
(* ModR(1.2,1)=0.2 and ModR(-1.2,1)=0.8 *)
var
  absy: Double;
begin
  if y=0.0 then begin
    Result := 0.0;
  end else begin
    absy := abs(y);
    Result := PosFrac(x/absy)*absy;
  end;
end;

function Mod360(const x: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := ModR(x, 360.0);
end;
```

This code will bring all angles into the range `0` to `360`. For example:

```
Writeln(Round(Mod360(5-10)));
Writeln(Round(Mod360(5-360)));
Writeln(Round(Mod360(5-720)));
Writeln(Round(Mod360(5+720)));
```

outputs:

```
355
5
5
5
```

Comment: @Marjan This code has been running in OrcaFlex for 25 years. The unusual comment style is because the code hasn't been changed since the days when the code was Modula-2!

Comment: 25 years huh? Nice! And didn't even notice the comment style. I often use `(*  *)` to copy paste stuff I'm working from, to distinguish it from normal comments and to avoid the non-nestability of `{  }` comments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any, but I'd prefer using a more general solution anyway ...

```
Procedure IncOverFlow(var Value:Double;Difference:Double;Limit:Double=360);
begin
   Value := Value + Difference;
   While Value < 0 do Value := Value + Limit;
   While Value >= Limit do Value := Value -Limit;
end;
```

Comment: Considering every formula I've ended up using takes radians, I tend to use `DegToRad` and `RadToDeg`.

Comment: @Petesh help me, I can't see the context to the question.
Some API's use degrees, on the surface it's usual.

Comment: I'm not knocking your answer; it's great for a general float-based increment function. It's just that `RadToDeg(DegToRad(Value + Increment)))` will give, more-or-less, the same answer (+/- the usual conversion errors)

Comment: I tryed this after your first post
Showmessage(FloatToStr(RadToDeg(DegToRad(350 + 70)))); 
What I got was 420 ...

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure WrapAngle(var Degs: Integer);
begin
  Degs := Degs mod 360;
  if Degs < 0 then
    Inc(Degs, 360);
end;
```