# What's the appropriate way to prevent a value out of range in an implicit class operator?

Tags: delphi, range, implicit-conversion

A small piece of [what I'm working on](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79214/converting-delphi-colors-between-tcolor-rgb-cmyk-and-hsv) is leading me to create my own record type which requires a particular range of a `Double`. For example, in the `HSV` color model, the Hue is represented as a double ranging from `0` to `360`. I cannot define this type the same way that you can do an inteter:

```
type
  THue = 0.0..360.0;
```

just does not work. So, I'm making a record with implicit class operators to be compatible with a `Double`:

```
type
  THue = record
  private
    FValue: Double;
  public
    class operator implicit(Value: THue): Double;
    class operator implicit(Value: Double): THue;
  end;

class operator THue.implicit(Value: THue): Double;
begin
  Result:= Value.FValue;
end;

class operator THue.implicit(Value: Double): THue;
begin
  //Need to restrict range to 0..360 here...
  Result.FValue:= Value;
end;
```

However, when assigning `Double` --> `THue`, I'm not sure what the appropriate approach is for asserting the `0..360` range. I could raise an exception, use an `Assert` statement, raise a compiler error, automatically change the value to be in range, or something else I'm not thinking about.

I'm naturally drawn to raising my own exception type such as `EValueOutOfRange` but a compiler error would make more sense.

In this scenario, how should I prevent assigning an out-of-range value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot validate the range for you. You will just have to either:

1. adjust the value to make sure it does not exceed the range:

   ```
   class operator THue.implicit(Value: Double): THue;
   begin
     if Value < 0.0 then Value := 0.0
     else if Value > 360.0 then Value := 360.0;
     Result.FValue := Value;
   end;
   ```
2. raise an exception (this also applies to asserts, which can be turned off, so not the best option):

   ```
   class operator THue.implicit(Value: Double): THue;
   begin
     if (Value < 0.0) or (Value > 360.0) then raise ...;
     Result.FValue := Value;
   end;
   ```

Those are your options.

Comment: Since adjusting the value to be in range would produce obscure results, I'm afraid exceptions are the only option then.. I was kinda hoping this wasn't the case. However, I may take the best of both worlds and modify the value to be in range and then raise an exception.

Comment: @JerryDodge It sounds a bit like (from the range) that the value is some kind of degree. Would it make sense to do the same as when using trigonemtric functions, ie. do a MOD operation (something like "WHILE Value>360.0 DO Value:=Value-360.0;") to force it into the range, but still preserve the "degrees"?

Comment: @HeartWare, I think Jerry is aware of the `Math.DegNormalize()` function which does that. See [Is there a function to shift degrees of a circle past 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13327187/576719).

Comment: @Jerry You can't do both. If you raise an exception then the conversion operator doesn't return a value. Functions that raise don't return values.